# Why does CoffeeScript compile a single param function in this way?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I'm trying to understand CoffeeScript function syntax.

Why does this line:

```
x => x
```

compile to:

```
 x(() => {
   return x;
 });
```

instead of:

```
 x => {
   return x;
 }
```

This can be seen at this [playground](http://coffeescript.org/#try:x%20%3D%3E%20x%0A)

Why does it think the first x is a function name, instead of a parameter as expected?

Comment: Don't know CoffeeScript but it seems like `(x) => x` does compile normally to `(x) => { return x; }` However, removing the brackets around the parameter breaks it. Weird.

Answer (score 2):

The [reference](http://coffeescript.org/#functions) says

> You don’t need to use parentheses to invoke a function if you’re passing arguments. The implicit call wraps forward to the end of the line or block expression.

and

> Functions are defined by an optional list of parameters in parentheses, an arrow, and the function body. The empty function looks like this: `->`.

So your `=> x` is the same as `() => x`, and writing it after `x` makes that first `x` a call. To make `x` a parameter name, use `(x) => x`.

Comment: This explains most of it thanks.  It's still odd that it thinks x is a function to invoke.  Does this mean any unknown name is assumed to be a function call?

Comment: No. Any expression followed by another expression is a function call - see the first quote. Normally you'd write `f 1` or `$.ajax "url", (result) -> console.log result`.